# How to change the way an object reflects the environment?

Tags: rendering, image, reflection

I would like to know if it is possible to adjust the way a mesh reflects the environment map.
I have 2 meshes on my scene. One seems to reflect the environment correctly (it's an imported mesh), the other (the one that I created) seems to distort it and the reflection image is too big.
UV are properly unwrap and face orientation is correct.

Thank you for your help!
[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here is the file. 
The only way I found to have the same reflection is to deform the mesh with a simple deform modifier.
I don't know if there is a way without modifying the mesh.
Thank you

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=j76d9AY8" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/j76d9AY8/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because the top lenses are convex, while the bottom ones are flat:

[image]

If you make them slightly convex (here with a spherical *Proportional Editing* on) it looks like they reflect the same:

[image]

Comment: Ok I got it! Thank you!